# How to construct makefile to compile AND run the binary?

Tags: c++, makefile

I would like to compile and run in one rule. Now I have :

```
CC = g++

%: %.o
    $(LINK.c) $^ -o $@; 
    ./$@
```

But the make only compiles the source to binary, but do not run it. How to construct make to do this in one step?

Having file `foo.cpp`. Applying the makefile:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin/2$ make foo
g++     foo.cpp   -o foo
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin/2$
```

Compilation is done. After which I want to run it (and see the output of that program), but that will not happen.

EDIT:
Please use **patterns**, I will not accept solution with explicit filenames.

Comment: Try `$(LINK.c) $^ -o $@ && ./$@`

Comment: Sorry, but did not work

Comment: Any outputs, error messages? I just took that from [colirus](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) standard command line.

Comment: The same as without `&&`. It compiles, but do not run, no errors

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Man, I thought this trivial-five-line example is not needed to show how I trigger it. But for you I edited it

Comment: There's obviously a different (probably standard) rule executed, than the one you had defined. That's one thing we cannot see without a mcve.

Comment: How could be trigger a explicit rule, when I provide recipe? Does not that override the explicit rule from make? I just want to define my own **pattern** rule to compile&run with my own recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are being tripped up by the implicit rules in `make`. It already knows how to a) make an object file from a C++ source and b) how to link.

So I suggest to rewrite the `Makefile` to be more explicit.  One example would be

```
all:
    g++ -c hello.cpp
    g++ -o hello hello.o
    ./hello
```

where I redefine the default `all` target and (for simplicity) make the steps explicit.  With a trivial file such as this

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world." << std::endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

it works as expected:

```
$ make
g++ -c hello.cpp
g++ -o hello hello.o
./hello
Hello, world.
$
```

You can refine and adapt as needed, *i.e.* with the `$^` and `$@` variables as needed.

*Edit:*  Here is a second variant. It does "nothing" as building a executable from (same-named) source file is known to `make`. So here I just do three things:

1. establish the names of all sources
2. derive the names of all programs from all sources
3. tell the `all` target to run the programs one-by-one

The following (minimal) `Makefile` does that:

```
sources :=  $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs := $(sources:.cpp=)

all:    $(programs)
        ./$^
```

Works as expected:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 94 Nov 15 16:36 hello.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 88 Nov 15 17:13 Makefile
$ make
g++     hello.cpp   -o hello
./hello
Hello, world.
$
```

I actually use that very same pattern in an example directory with 18 or so example [in this repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/blob/master/inst/examples/standard/GNUmakefile).

*Edit 2:*  The above actually run one command over all targets in `programs`; I copied it from `strip` invocation where that makes sense.  One may to have them all run after they have been built is to use this:

```
sources :=  $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs := $(sources:.cpp=)

all:    $(programs)
        for p in $(programs); do ./$$p; done
```

Comment: But I want the pattern there. I do not want to specify each file by its own, that is not general

Comment: As I said you can I just wanted to point the general issue that the rule you wrote may actually not be called -- explaining why you don;t you see executable running.

Comment: There is one thing seems not working properly. If I have more sources in current dir (or dir where makefile is), say I have files `foo.cpp bar.cpp`. Then the rule will compile both, but the recipe `./$^` will run it as `./foo bar`. So it takes the second program as argument to the first one (because of `$^` which is all files). Also, the rule is incomplete -> from all the programs (compiled from sources), which one should be the one executed? Or is the rule suppose to run each one by one? That is not my user-case. I want to explicitly run just one selected (by `make foo`).

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. There is an alternative.  So maybe I had this wrong from my use and `$^` is "the right hand side of the rule" i.e. all target.  There is another, maybe `$<` that is the name of the invoking one.  Worst case you may have to trim the .cpp or .o extension off.  I _have_ done what you want to do (just because I wanted to see the looping done) but it may need a different built-in variable.

Comment: never mind, I am probrably looking for `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, Where I can directly manipulate the target name, which is the name of the file I want to compile&run, you have given me a direction at least, so thanks

Comment: Or maybe it won't. Hard to tell.  But follow the link I gave to the _actual_ Makefile I use and it has for target `run` an explicit shell loop:  `@for p in $(programs); do echo; echo "Running $$p:"; ./$$p; done`

Comment: I thought about this some more.  First, from a glance the documentation, `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` is likely _not_ what you want; it seems to merely refer to the command-line arguments.  Second, the key idea behind `make` is that it automagically resolves and runs the _implicit_ build steps stemming from the simple declaration of rules.  Hence, the 'looping' over your targets is maybe too deeply engrained in `make` for you to hook into to. So unrolling the targets as I (see previous comment) may be all there is.

Comment: `e-%: %.o
 $(CC) $*.o -o $*
 ./$*`

Comment: Nice. Close enough to my every original comment that an implicit rule was already present and covering your case---so you need to redefine it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel `$<` is the first prerequisite in the recipe. i.e., given `target: preq1 preq2 preq3`, `$@` is `target`, `$<` is `preq1`, and `$^` is `preq1 preq2 preq3`. There are [more automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), but those are the most common positional automatic variables.

Comment: @MatthewCole Sure, as 30+ year user of `make` I am quite aware.

Comment: @DirkEddbuettel well, to be fair, “ There is another, maybe $< that is the name of the invoking one” is a mistake a 30 year user of make could easily have.

Comment: @MatthewCole I am sure we can recap the Make documentation of cheat sheet here <wink>.  There are indeed a handful of these variables.